# Animated SVGs don't animate when oneboxed in chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

If I post a lovely animated SVG here, it will animate:

[image]

Beautiful, but the same does not happen in chat for me (Chrome, Mac OS):

[image]

This is a serious bug which needs fixing immedia-- **ALL GLORY TO THE HYPNOTOAD**

Comment: This seems to be working in Firefox, but not chrome, haven't tested other browsers.

Comment: @StrixVaria The image in the post *does* animate for me, but chat doesn't.

Comment: Animates fine on Firefox 19.0.2 compiled from source on Linux. Browser bugs ftw!

Comment: I *must* stop looking at this toad!!!

Comment: Likely because the image tag was added to the DOM with script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an issue with Chrome. There's no problem with Firefox.

On the other hand, SVG animations in Chrome/WebKit are still not well supported/have bugs.

- For example, try the [w3.org test](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20061213/svggen/animate-elem-34-t.svg) in both browsers.
- See also: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21371

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's not an issue with chat *playing* the animation, because if you load a chat room with an animation it will play, but if posted while you're already in the room.

I assume the issue is that chat is not telling the browser to play the graphic when it is loaded.